# Как использовать react-dimensions с redux connect()

Tags: reactjs, redux

В компоненте есть код, функция коннект редакса

```
export default connect(
   (state, ownProps) => ({
       ownProps,
       data: state.data,
   })
)(PageExample)
```

В документации к react-dimensions предлагается такой код

```
export default Dimensions({
   getHeight: function(element) {
       ...
   },
   getWidth: function(element) {
       ...
   }
})(PageExample);
```

Не понятно как использовать его совместно с функцией коннект, что нужно написать чтобы в props появились нужные значения react-dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно воспользоваться compose из redux, она позволяет применять несколько enhancers.

Вот документация:

https://redux.js.org/api-reference/compose

Тогда ваш export перепишется так:

```
export default compose(
    connect((state, ownProps) => ({ ownProps, data: state.data })),
    Dimensions({ 
         getHeight: function(element) { ... },
         getWidth:function(element) { ... }
    })
)(PageExample)
```

Comment: Прекрасно. Большое спасибо